# How to change colour and font of shiny dashboard title?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can i change the title of this dashboard title header to be the following :

I want it to say Basic **DASHBOARD** where DASHBOARD is in BOLD, RED FONT and Basic is in the default white font - i also want to adjust the size of the font of DASHBOARD to be somewhat larger? any ideas of how to do this in shiny dashboard title?

so basically needs to be RED and BOLD for DASHBOARD and larger, BASIC stays the same,

code below

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),

      box(
        title = "Controls",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use inline `css` to achieve that:

```
dashboardHeader(title = span("Basic ", 
                             span("dashboard", 
                             style = "color: red; font-size: 28px")))
```

Comment: wHAT ABOUT BOLD FONT?

Comment: add `font-weight: bold;` to the style. You should familiarize yourself with HTML/css. Good resource is here: https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: cheers for the help will check it out!!!!! thanks a bunch really great answer accepted!

Comment: But the problem is dashboardHeader width is too small to fit in long titles. How do we increase the width?

Comment: Look at the `titleWidth` argument of `dashboardHeader`